# jQuery "request.term" substitute

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using [jquery mobile autocomplete](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/blob/master/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.1.js) for my mobile web app. It seems to not let me use "request.term" as my dynamic query, so I'm trying to create the `liveQuery()` function below that will return the val() of my input field as I type.

The goal is for this returned value to be passed along as a parameter to the `generateUrl()` function to be prepended to a url.

This liveQuery function is returning `undefined`, although when I log `$(this).val()` to the console I can see what I type. Would appreciate some direction on how to pass a dynamic variable (my query) to my `generateUrl()` function. Thanks.

```
  var liveQuery = function() {
    $("#remote_mobile_search").keyup(function() {
      return $(this).val() ;
    })
  }

  $("#remote_mobile_search").autocomplete({
    source: generateUrl(liveQuery()),
    ...
```

Comment: i don't understand what your are trying to do. BTW, you return nothing from liveQuery

Comment: I'm trying to pass a realtime-changing variable (what I'm typing into #remote_mobile_search) to generateUrl() as a parameter.

Comment: But the autocomplete initialization will be run only once, here i think you are initialize it on DOM ready before any value has been filled inside #remote_mobile_search. And again, anyway you are returning nothing from liveQuery function

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I see in source code of plugin, there is an update method, this should be used instead

---

Maybe try this but it is really really weird {each time you enter something in input, the autocomplete plugin is reinitialized}:

```
 $("#remote_mobile_search").keyup(function () {
       $(this).autocomplete('update',generateUrl(this.value));
    })

   $("#remote_mobile_search").autocomplete();
```

generateUrl() function is supposed to return something of course and to be SYNCHRON. As and don't know code of this function, I'm not sure you are doing it right.

Comment: OK - if the autocomplete source is in a file separate from the code I laid out in this post, how do I call that update method?

Comment: I would say: $(this).autocomplete('update',generateUrl(this.value));  Try and see. Sorry, i cannot test this plugin. Of course, you need the autocomplete plugin to be initialized before calling this method.